# Java lambda help -- act on multiple member variables of list of objects

Tags: java, lambda

If I want to add all of the values of a list or even array, I could use:

```
List<MyObject> newList = ...
myObjects.stream().forEach(x -> newList.add(x));
```

However, what if instead of wanting to do this with with the whole object, I want to act on member variables of the objects instead, where those values are also lists?

If I wasn't using lambdas, I would write code like:

```
List<String> var1list = ...
List<String> var2list = ...
for (MyObject myObject : myObjects) {
  var1List.addAll(myObject.getVar1Values());
  var2List.addAll(myObject.getVar2Values());
}
```

Please give me some tips on the proper way to write this kind of expression (even if the best solution is to not use lambdas), and also why that is the correct approach.

Comment: `myObjects.stream().forEach(x -> {var1list.addAll(x.getVar1Values()); var2list.addAll(x.getVar2Values()); });`?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy you don't need to use `.stream()` with this solution.

Comment: What's wrong with your current solution?  Seems pretty straight forward to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to loop through the myobject and trying to do some logic over it.

it should be like.

```
List<String> var1list = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> var2list = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<MyObject> myObjects = Arrays.asList(new MyObject("1", "2"), new MyObject("3", "4"));
        
        myObjects.forEach((obj)->{
            var1list.add(obj.getVar1());
            var2list.add(obj.getVar2());
        });
```

Comment: I suggest you match the ops method names, etc.

Answer (score 1):

do you mean this?

```
myObjects.stream()
   .map((it) -> it.getVar1Values())
   .forEach((it) ->{
     var1List.addAll(it);
     var2List.addAll(it);
})
```

Comment: You don't need to stream the list to do this.

Comment: @WJS why is bad way to use stream? I have heard and that's why I am asking about it

Comment: I never said it was bad.  I said you don't need to use it. `myObjects` is a list and it supports `forEach` directly.  So you can do `myObjects.forEach(it-> {var1List.addAll(it.getVar1Values()); var2List.addAll(it.getVar2Values());};`